# Spring data jpa exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

While retrieving records from the DB table we are getting exceptions. I tried the same for another table it worked but for this table, it's not working. I am using `spring-data-jpa`

```
@Entity
@Table(name=USR.TABLE_NAME)

public class USR implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public final static String TABLE_NAME = "usr_profile";


@Id
@Column (name="USR_NO")
private Integer usrNo;

@Column (name="USR_Address", length=20, nullable=true, unique=false)
private Integer usrAddress;

@Column (name="USR_COUNTRY", nullable=true, unique=false)
private String usrCountry;

other fields constructor, no-arg constructor, getter and setter removed for brevity
```

```
@Repository
public interface USRRepository extends JpaRepository<USR, Integer> {

@Query("SELECT o.usrNo, o.usrAddress, o.usrCountry, o.usrState, o.usrSt FROM USR o WHERE o.usrNo=?1") 
USR findUsrRecordByUsrNo(Integer usrNo);
}
```

Here I have created a Controller class that has a get mapping

```
@GetMapping ("/CmpUsr")
public ResponseEntity<String> cmpLookup() {
USR us = usrRepository.findUsrRecordByUsrNo(12557);
return new ResponseEntity<>(us.toString(), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

I am getting this exception

SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServiet] in context with path[] threw exception (Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.Object[]] to type [com.newprof.userApp.domain.USR] for value (12557, 115 Minesota Yellow Rd, US, PH, 000991); nested exception is
org.springframework.core.comvert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.Integer to type [com.newprof.userApp.domain.USR]] with root cause

Comment: Show all constructors of USR class. Empty, not empty, semi empty. All you got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code. I think the problem is the return object witch is not the same with select values.

```
@Repository
public interface USRRepository extends JpaRepository<USR, Integer> {

   @Query("SELECT o FROM USR o WHERE o.usrNo=?1") 
   USR findUsrRecordByUsrNo(Integer usrNo);

}
```

Comment: I have taken only for columns fields values and can u tell what is wrong in my query please

Comment: If he was to fetch entire USR he wouldn't need the @Query thing.

Comment: The query will return an object of type USR. If you specify columns in select option, you must also specify the path to the custom class for the query response. to avoid that, the sample way is to do @Query("SELECT o FROM USR o WHERE o.usrNo=?1"). So the query will return o witch is an USR object.

Comment: why would I write a query I will directly use ```findById()``` then

Comment: Yes it's the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
@Query("SELECT o.usrNo, o.usrAddress, o.usrCountry, o.usrState, o.usrSt FROM USR o WHERE o.usrNo=?1") 
USR findUsrRecordByUsrNo(Integer usrNo);
}
```

with this:

```
@Query("SELECT new com.newprof.userApp.domain.USR(o.usrNo, o.usrAddress, o.usrCountry, o.usrState, o.usrSt) FROM USR o WHERE o.usrNo=?1") 
USR findUsrRecordByUsrNo(Integer usrNo);
}
```

In exception it says: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.Object[]] to type [com.newprof.userApp.domain.USR].

Which basically means that your query statement returns an **object array**: java.lang.Object[].

So my plan is, you call your **USR constructor** straightaway in your query.

**EDIT**

FOUND THE ANSWER.

So you added this into your query:

```
new com.newprof.userApp.domain.USR(o.usrNo, o.usrAddress, o.usrCountry, o.usrState, o.usrSt)
```

And it now says to you: Cannot resolve constructor com.newprof.userApp.domain.USR(). IT IS RUGHT. Because **there is no such constructor**. You need to add it to your entity.

You need to add something like this:

```
public USR (Integer usrNo, Integer usrAddress, String usrCountry, String usrState, String usrSt) {
this.usrNo = usrNo;
this.usrAddress = usrAddress;
this.usrCountry = usrCountry;
this.usrState = usrState;
this.usrSt = isrSt;
}
```

This brand new Constructor will be called in statement `new com.newprof.userApp.domain.USR(o.usrNo, o.usrAddress, o.usrCountry, o.usrState, o.usrSt)` :D

Comment: I saw this  ``` new  <package> ```  for the first time and I am getting compile-time exception ``` identifier expected got '<' ``` where t make the difference

Comment: @Learners I wrote it <package> for you to include the real package of your USR class )))

Comment: But why do we need to do this I was asking

Comment: @Learners Explained in my answer.

Comment: Even when I add the package name it's showing compile-time exceptions. ```Cannot resolve constructor <package>.USR()```

Comment: do you add full name of your class?

Comment: This is happening only with this table and happened for first time

Comment: I mean for example com.example.someproject.entity.USR

Comment: @Learners This is JPA. Weird stuff happens.

Comment: Yes, i have tried everything :)

Comment: Show your constructors. Obviously it cannot fill them, which means you need to show me your constructors))

Comment: constructor has a lot of other fields also. It too large to show here

Comment: @Learners updated answer. Try to add the constructor.

Comment: Now what I have done is I have removed the default and all args constructor

Comment: Why? Do you think they can't stand each other with the third constructor?

Comment: @Learners You did absolutely redundant thing. I suggested adding constructor, not removing all the others. HIBERNATE DOES NEED and Empty Constructor, and AllArgsConstructors. You can't just remove them like that. You shouldn't.

Comment: LOL, No I just thought let's remove the constructors and run the old query which I have posted in my question. Actually i compared other entity i don't have constructor there and it's working fine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243866/discussion-between-learners-and-vusal).